# Login to ADFS from Spring without SAML

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, adfs, acs, accesscontrolservice

We are building a Spring Boot 2 application that enables SSO with ADFS.
We already implemented SAML with browser profile but we now need to serve clients who do not have a web browser.

From talking to people who operate the ADFS side they say there is a way to login into ADFS without SAML but can't point me in the right direction on how to implement it.
What is the ADFS endpoint, GET/POST what is the parameter structure?

Has anyone implemented that (Not necessarily in Spring) and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios . This gives you options to consider when a browser is unavailable. The device code flow explained here is intended for console apps or devices without a browser that handle the authentication using another device with a web browser.